# PHP/PDO/MySQL: Convert Multiple Queries Into Single Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

*(Yes, I have "thoroughly searched for an answer before asking my question"... but haven't found the "right" answer to my issue. I have read the MySQL man about user variables... I have read the PHP man regarding PDO... still can't grok the solution.)*

**I'm trying to get from PHP code the same result set returned from this SQL statement that executes correctly and successfully within PhpMyAdmin:**

```
SET @x := 0;

SELECT * 
FROM (

   SELECT 
   `o`.`timestamp`
   `o`.`v_phase_a` ,
   `o`.`v_phase_b` ,
   `o`.`v_phase_c` ,
   (@x := @x+1) AS x
   FROM `operational_parameters` AS o
   WHERE `o`.`timestamp` >= '2014-01-21 05:00:00'
   AND `o`.`timestamp` <= '2014-02-04 04:59:30'
   ORDER BY `o`.`timestamp`

) t
WHERE x MOD 336 = 0;
```

The rationale for the type of result set is a long story and rooted in my client's business requirements. It's supposed to represent a uniform sampling of data stored as rows inserted 30 seconds apart over a given time span, in this case 2 weeks... this particular statement returns exactly 120 rows of data, which are then packaged by PHP and sent to the UI to be charted with the jqplot plug-in...

Everything else works excellently well, except that within PHP  I'm unable to execute multiple SQL statements, a process which I believe would be required to SET my user variable @x, for use in the subsequent SELECT statement. Again, this SQL runs just fine when queried against my database using phpMyAdmin...

I do realize that generally speaking, within PHP, one cannot execute multiple SQL statements in a single query...

**Is it possible, however, to create a SINGLE SQL statement - as a string - that will fetch the same result set as that returned by MySQL using the phpMyAdmin tool and the SQL I've listed above?** A single statement that I can pass to my newly created PDO inside my PHP and get the right number of rows?

(Seems like PDOs are supposed to be able to handle such a scenario, at least that's what I've gleaned from my study of this board...)

I'm sort of new to PHP/MySQL, so I'm ready to learn. Teach on!

Answer (score 2):

You can move the initialization into a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT o.timestamp , o.v_phase_a , o.v_phase_b , o.v_phase_c , (@x := @x+1) AS x
      FROM operational_parameters AS o cross join
           (select @x := 0) const
      WHERE o.timestamp >= '2014-01-21 05:00:00' AND o.timestamp <= '2014-02-04 04:59:30'
      ORDER BY o.timestamp
     ) t
WHERE x MOD 336 = 0;
```

Comment: Perfect! I've learned something today. After implementing in PHP, this SQL returns the perfect result set every time. Many, many thanks, to you Mr. Linoff, and to stackoverflow. Frickin' awesome!